# How to make a notification coming from Firebase console to pop up like Facebook and other apps?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase cloud messaging to push notifications to my app and I managed to get everything to work perfectly but was surprised that the notification doesn't pop up like other apps like Facebook and so, it only appears in the notification tray. So any help ?

Comment: read about heads up notifications: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

Comment: It says that I need to set the notification priority for API 25 and lower and set the importance for 26 and higher ... I am using Notification.Builder which has setPriority() but couldn't find setImportance

Answer (score 0):

ShortcutBadger is a library that do your job. Works with LG, Sony, Samsung, MI, HTC and other custom Launchers.

```
    int badgeCount = 1;
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);
ShortcutBadger.with(getApplicationContext()).count(badgeCount);
```

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...  I don't want a counter on the app icon ... I want the notification to pop up at the top of the screen like facebook and other apps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rafal Malek, I figured out that I need to set the priority to my notification builder to high ... but setPriority() is deprecated in Notification.Builder which I have been using so you guys make sure to use NotificaitonCompat.Builder instead.